# How to get selected radio button text in datalist ?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In below data list represents set of question's and answer, How to check whether the user selected right answer radio button or not when the user clicks on submit button using javascript ?

the answer is stored in database.

Datalist:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="Qno" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            Qno:
            <asp:Label ID="QnoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Qno") %>' />
            <br />
            Question:
            <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ans1") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ans2") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ans3") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ans4") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a CommandName parameter for the Button2 in the DataList: *CommandName="Validate"*

Add the OnItemCommand event for the DataList1: *OnItemCommand="DataList1_OnItemCommand"*

In the code behind, fill-in the *DataList1_OnItemCommand* event actions:

```
protected void DataList1_OnItemCommand(object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
 if (String.Equals(e.CommandName, "Validate"))
 {
  DataListItem dataItem = (DataListItem )e.Item;
  RadioButton rbtn1 = (RadioButton)dataItem.FindControl("RadioButton1");
  RadioButton rbtn2 = (RadioButton)dataItem.FindControl("RadioButton2");
  RadioButton rbtn3 = (RadioButton)dataItem.FindControl("RadioButton3");
  RadioButton rbtn4 = (RadioButton)dataItem.FindControl("RadioButton4");

  // Code to check which radio button was checked.
  if(rbtn1 != null && rbtn1.Checked)
  {

  }
  else if(rbtn2 != null && rbtn2.Checked)
  {

  } //Perform these for the remaining two check boxes
 }
}
```

Take required actions based on which check box is checked.

Comment: i got error No overload for 'DataList1_OnItemCommand' matches delegate 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListCommandEventHandler'

Comment: Earlier I provided the answer without checking the syntax in the IDE. I have now edited my earlier answer by fixing some incorrect syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much Anil i got answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Always ensure that valid answer(s) as marked as accepted so that someone else with the same question can easily find the answer.